# We had a issue in V50.0.1 for the drop down background color is not displaying

Tags: firefox, background

We are facing the below problem in V50.0.1, V50.0.2,

Dropdown background color is not working in  tag. Could you please check and get back to us with the correct solution or information. For this case we are using the "Refresh Firefox" frequently to clear this issue. But this is not the proper solution for us to handle.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with e10s (multiprocess architecture) in Firefox being tracked in [bug 910022](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910022).